# Is Klippel Feil Syndrome hereditary? Recessive/Dominant? Liklihood of passing it to offspring?

Tags: heredity, klippel-feil-syndrome, genetic-predisposition, dominant-gene, recessive-gene

I assume Klippel Feil Syndrome (KFS) is genetic/hereditary because my sister and I both have it, and it's a rare disease.  But if I'm wrong, please do correct me. **Is KFS genetic-hereditary?** *My brothers don't have KFS, but are they carriers?*

**Additionally, does this mean that one of my parents had KFS or that both of them were carriers?**

**If one has KFS, what are the probabilities that they will pass it onto their children?**

**Is it a recessive gene/trait (not dominant)?**

Basically, I just want to know what the likelihood of me passing on KFS to my children would be -- and if they don't get KFS -- they  become carriers for it, correct?